# Locking a ColdFusion Application Variable that points to instance of an object

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, locking, scope

I'm running my applications on CF 9. I created a CFC to concentrate my cookie handling instead of all the  tags strewn about. It is simple. It has two attributes (name, value), and has 5 methods (setCookie, deleteCookie, verifyCookie, clearAllCookies, and init).

Since I wanted this method to be available throughout the application, I put this code in the onApplicationStart method of my application.cfc file:

```
application.oCookie = createObject("com.mycookie").init();
```

When I need to set a cookie in any code file I just call it like so:

```
application.oCookie.name="testCookieName";
application.oCookie.value="testCookieValue";
application.oCookie.setCookie();
```

My question is: Do I need to put a lock on this code each time I do this? If two separate users were to be on pages accessing this code at the same exact instant, can I end up with mixed up cookie values being set?

Answer (score 5):

To make your `oCookie` thread-safe, it has to be a singleton (with no state) that only acts as a thin layer to the `<cfcookie>` or the `cookie` scope.

Therefore you should design your `com.mycookie` so that it accepts `application.oCookie.setCookie(name, value)` instead.  And make sure you var-scope everything and don't store anything in the `variables` scope of `mycookie`.

And I don't think you need to use cflock.

If you haven't already, you may want to checkout [WireBox](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/WireBox.cfm).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I didn't realize calling that with passed arguments instead of modifying the properties and then calling the method would run as a single thread. It makes sense. It also has the added bonus of reducing the number of lines needed when I call it!

Comment: Yes, when you do `oCookie.X=Y`, it's the same as setting `this.X` in `com.mycookie` class.  `this` scope and `variables` scope of a CFC are local to the CFC instance.  If there's only one instance they will be shared.  Therefore, you should only rely on `arguments` and `local` scope for inputs, and have only constants in `variables` scope.  `This` scope is really only meant for public functions, less for properties.